# Can the Lenovo T440p display 1080p resolution with an Intel 4600 graphics card?

Tags: windows-10, 1080p

I have a Lenovo T440p with an Intel 4600 graphics card, and I want to set my resolution to 1080p. When I connect my TV and clone both displays, the laptop screen adapts to the higher resolution and displays 1920x1080. However, I have been unable to find a way to do this without the TV being connected. The native resolution is 1366x768, and 1080p is not an available setting. I have tried custom resolutions, but they do not allow it, saying the hardware cannot do it. I have also tried 'Detect' and other methods, as well as CRU and going into the registry. I understand that there is no reason why I cannot output a high resolution into any screen, but it would result in a poor image quality. All I want is smaller icons, taskbar, etc., more space, and I do not care about the actual pixel resolution or if I cannot even read the text under the icons.

My first idea was to use an HDMI emulator that would be 1920x1080 and then clone that "virtual" monitor, which is not physically there, to the laptop screen. Does anyone know of a way or a simple software, etc. that can help me achieve this?

Comment: There's a lot of "noise" in your question (and even in its title), which is not relevant at all. Please [edit] your question to remove that. Also, please see https://superuser.com/help/formatting Success!

Comment: “theres no reason anyway you cant output a 4k reso into any crappy monitor” – but there is. The monitor’s controller has to support it. If it doesn’t, you simply will not get anything displayed at all.

Comment: yes, but i am not talking about sending a 4K signal, i means downscaling before sending the signal...  and anyway thats not the point my screen can already display 1080p, i just want to be able to do it without having the tv connected.

Answer (score -1):

Its actually easy if you have Nvidia Graphics:
Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pESZp2tFcx0) where it shows you how you can change and enter a custom resolution using the Nvidia Control Panel.

Open Nvidia control panel > under Display select change resolution > Click Customize > Check "Enable resolutions not exposed by the display" > Click Create Custom Resolution > Enter Horizontal and vertical as 1920 and 1080 respectively > Click Test > Click yes to save resolution > then change the resolution by right clicking on the desktop as you normally would and select 1920 * 1080.

But I am not sure about Intel graphics ...i will check and let you know...do you have only Intel graphics or Nvidia as well

Ok so for Intel graphics, Open Intel HD graphics control panel (right click on desktop and the option should be there) > Click on Display > On the left side select Custom Resolutions > You will get a warning > Proceed at your own risk > Enter Width and height as 1920 and 1080 respectively and click OK.

If you don't have Intel HD graphics control panel, then download your graphics drivers from Intel website

Comment: ya, as i said this doesnt work... dont have Nvidia and custom resolution is not allowed on intel HD graph... it state: "The custom resolution exceeds the maximum bandwidth capacity"...  from what i understood by looking around is that its far from been a limitation of the computer or the graph card,... i was driving 3 displays including one ultra wide 3440x1440 i think with this laptop, so... it has to do with the way LCD panel manufacturer are rating their display on what it can and cant do, must be a file somewhere stating these "wanna be" specs for the OS to use...

Comment: @YannLevesque  What value did you enter for Refresh Rate ?

Comment: @YannLevesque https://superuser.com/questions/957222/enable-4k-3840-x-2160-resolution-on-windows-7-with-intel-hd-graphics-card

Comment: 60p...59p...30p....25p too i think, none lower... not the issue

Comment: its not an intel HD issue i believe, looks like a physical screen information issue